# Python ещё не сильно знаю, но как сделать так чтоб пользователь мог выбирать: Начать работу программы заново, или закрыть программу?

Tags: python

```
print("Привет! Это программа создана для перевода из десятичной сисетмы в любые другие системы 
счисления")

a = int(input("Введите число которое хотите конвертировать: "))

n = int(input("Введите систему в которую хотите перевести число: "))

s = ""

while a > 0:

        s = str(a % n) + s 

        a //= n

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основное тело программы можно поместить в бесконечный цикл.
В конце работы проверять ввод пользователя и если он хочет выйти, то прерывать данный цикл.
Например, так:

```
print("Привет! Это программа создана для перевода из десятичной сисетмы в любые другие системы счисления")

while True:    

    a = int(input("Введите число которое хотите конвертировать: "))

    n = int(input("Введите систему в которую хотите перевести число: "))

    s = ""

    while a > 0:

            s = str(a % n) + s 

            a //= n
    print(s)
    cnt = int(input(('Введите 1, что бы продолжить или 0 для завершения работы')))
    if cnt == 0:
          break
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Green, спасибо тебе большое)